# C# - Import lines from a text file into a Process.Start statement

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am currently trying to import a list of executables from a text file into a statement:

```
private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("test.exe", <Process Name Here>);
}
```

So If a text file named process.txt contained:

> notepad.exe
>
> calc.exe

I would end up with:

```
Process.Start("test.exe", notepad.exe);
```

and

```
Process.Start("test.exe", cacl.exe);
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that your list of .exes will be a) on one line in the file and b) not contain any spaces in the .exe filename?

Comment: @Will A The exe's might have spaces in them, but they will me on individual lines

Comment: The wisdom of this approach seems strongly correlated to your control naming choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to be what you're after, Michael.

```
foreach(string exename in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("yourfile.txt"))
{
  Process.Start("test.exe", "\"" + exename + "\"");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(pathToFile))
{
    string exe = "";

    while ((exe = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Process.Start("test.exe", exe);
    }
}
```